# change variable value in shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have 2 shell scripts and their contents are:

`1.txt`

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

`2.txt`

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Now I want to change `a=1` to `a=7` and `a=8`, so I write a shell script

```
f={7,8}
for i in {0..1}
do
    sed -i "s/a=1/a=${f[${i}]}/g" $i.txt
done
```

But failed. Can anybody figure it out?

Comment: `f={7,8}` does not define an array; `f=(7 8)` does.

Comment: Don't change your question to eliminate the problem completely. If your only problem is the incorrect assignment to `f`, this should just be closed as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To define an array use parentheses and no commas:

```
f=(7 8)
```

You also need to adjust `$i` by one to ensure the file names are correct:

```
sed -i "s/a=1/a=${f[i]}/g" "$((i+1)).txt"
```

(Notice that `${f[${i}]}` can be shortened to `${f[i]}` since array indices are evaluated in an arithmetic context where dollar signs are optional.)